# php Array to string conversion error on query concatenation

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel

//Laravel code
This is my php code I am not getting what is the error and where,please any one help me out

```
static function getall($input) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM radio_city";
    $where = [];
    $params = [];
    if ($input['city']) {
        $where[] = "city = ?"; 
        $params[] = $input['city']; 
    } else { 
        $where = ''; 
    } 
    $sql .= $where; 
    $sql .= "\nGROUP BY city"; 
    //echo $sql; 
    return DB::select($sql, $params);     
}
```

Comment: Whoa, format your code. And it seems you're attempting to concatenate an array with strings, as the error says. Check the type of your vars.

Comment: This is a very basic error, and your code appears to try to do the same thing twice, neither time correctly. Explain what you want to do, because simply adding an array to the end of your string won't work.

Comment: I am new to php so can anyone modify the code so that i can understand what and how

Comment: Just i am taking an input from select tag and passing it here to browse the database by that input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$input` and `$where` are both arrays and you're attempting to coerce string concatenation.

The lines in question are

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM radio_city WHERE city=".$input."";`

and

`$sql .= $where;`

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it appears to me that you should remove everything after "WHERE" in your stub SQL query.

Also, you'll have to make up your mind with respect to `$where`'s datatype, in either case you don't need that `else` block that sets `$where` to an empty string. So either initialize `$where` to an empty string and concatenate each condition with AND/OR, or initialize to an array and push either AND or OR conditions and then implode before concatenating to your stub.

Edit: just a shot in the dark of what you're looking for...

```
static function getall($input) {
    $where  = [];
    $params = [];
    $sql    = 'SELECT * FROM radio_city';

    if (isset($input['city']) && $input['city']) {
        $where[] = ' city = ?'; // Subsequent additions to $where should specify AND/OR conditional
        $params[] = $input['city']; 
    }

    $sql .= implode(',', $where); 
    $sql .= " GROUP BY city"; 

    return DB::select($sql, $params);     
}
```

Untested. Don't just copy & paste though. If it works, great, but see what's changed and try to really understand why it changed, or ask here if you don't know.

Comment: Thank You for help, I got it.Really I am glad for this answer,thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM radio_city WHERE city=".$input."";
```

Contradicts this:

```
if ($input['city']) { ....
```

What is $input?  Is it an array?  Is it a string?  If it is an array, as I suspect and as the second line suggests, the error will be with the first, and you probably want:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM radio_city WHERE city=" . $input['city'];
```

...though the second line suggest you aren't sure if $input['city'] exists.  Incidentally, better use empty() there:

```
if ( ! empty($input['city'])) { ....
```

As what you're doing is trying to evaluate what it appears you intend to be a string as a boolean value.

As Utkanos comments, though, Whoa!  Format the code, consider the logic more fully.  Not much point worrying about whether $input['city'] exists after you've concatenated it onto a string...

Comment: Thank you that was mistake but i have modified the code can you check once and please give a solution

Comment: Carlos has told you.  But, really, read the code, run some tests, use var_dump() - if you do not debug this stuff yourself, you will never move forward.